# Grid Binding in Windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am taking one grid having 3 rows and 3 columns .i want to bind the images to that grid actually images are added to grid but it is not added in correct way.i.e they are not   place with in cells of grid  .

How to bind  12 images correctly to cells of grid  .i want all images are having same size and width placing properly in that grid.

Comment: `plz urgent` for windows mobile 7, it isn't out until xmas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my version is more clearly (3 col, rows auto):

```
        ColumnDefinition coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
        coldef.MinWidth = 135;
        gridCat.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);
        coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
        coldef.MinWidth = 135;
        gridCat.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);
        coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
        coldef.MinWidth = 135;
        gridCat.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);

        RowDefinition rowdef = rowdef = new RowDefinition();
        rowdef.MinHeight = 135;
        gridCat.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);

        for (int i = 0; i < App.CatViewModel.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Image grid_image = new Image();
            ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();
            grid_image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty,  c.ConvertFromString("img/touro.png"));
            grid_image.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, 128.0);
            grid_image.SetValue(Image.HeightProperty, 128.0);

            if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            {
                rowdef = new RowDefinition();
                rowdef.MinHeight = 135;
                gridCat.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);
            }

            grid_image.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i/3);
            grid_image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i%3);
            gridCat.Children.Add(grid_image);

        }
```

Comment: Like the other answer, this isn't binding, all you're doing is creating an image and adding it to the grid controls.

Comment: is exextly what user lookup; additional you can add one or two way bindings; and or vlidation; and/or make resources autofit or use svg etc;

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="left" Name="grid_main" Visibility="collapsed">
 </Grid>
```

Here is the code which will arrange the 4 images in one row.

```
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++)
         {
           grid_image = new Image();
           ColumnDefinition coldef = new ColumnDefinition();
            coldef.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            grid_main.ColumnDefinitions.Add(coldef);
            // do this for each row
            RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
            rowdef.Height = GridLength.Auto;
            grid_main.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);
            Grid.SetColumn(grid_image, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(grid_image, 0);

            if (j < 4)
            {
                grid_image.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, k);
                grid_image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j++);
                grid_main.Children.Add(grid_image);
            }
            else
            {
                j = 0; k = k + 1;
                grid_image.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, k);
                grid_image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j++);
                grid_main.Children.Add(grid_image);
            }

        }
```

Comment: This isn't binding, all you're doing is creating an image and adding it to the grid controls.